# golang slice allocation performance

Tags: performance, memory, go

I stumbled upon an interesting thing while checking performance of memory allocation in GO.

```
package main

import (
      "fmt"
      "time"
    )

func main(){
   const alloc int = 65536
   now := time.Now()
   loop := 50000
   for i := 0; i<loop;i++{
      sl := make([]byte, alloc)
      i += len(sl) * 0
   }
   elpased := time.Since(now)
   fmt.Printf("took %s to allocate %d bytes %d times", elpased, alloc, loop) 
}
```

I am running this on a Core-i7 2600 with go version 1.6 64bit (also same results on 32bit) and 16GB of RAM (on WINDOWS 10)
so when alloc is 65536 (exactly 64K) it runs for 30 seconds (!!!!).
When  alloc is 65535 it takes ~200ms.
Can someone explain this to me please? 
I tried the same code at home with my core i7-920 @ 3.8GHZ but it didn't show same results (both took around 200ms). Anyone has an idea what's going on?

Comment: To add even more variation, trying your code on a Windows 7 (Go 1.6, 64 bit), I get 17 seconds no matter if `alloc` is `65536` or `65535`.

Comment: I'm not an expert on allocation internals, but I just want to mention that allocating a slice of 65536 bytes is actually allocating that plus 2 integers (the `len` and `cap` counters), so actually more than 64KB.

Comment: To add more informations to the problem, I ran the code on my Archlinux (i7-4720HQ @ 2.60GHz), and it takes consistently ~600ms. You should try to use the profiling tool on the setup that takes a long time. It's actually a good case to start learning it if you don't know it already.

Comment: You can try disabling the garbage collector (GOGC=off) to see if it is the issue. With 16 GB of RAM you should have plenty of memory for that.

Comment: yeah. set GOGC=off really improved performance. So I think I now understand what's going on. because of escape analysis golang allocates memory on the heap and then the gc needs to clean it. when I allocate less than 64K, go uses the stack. when the array is on the stack it'll clean iteself and also the allocation will take only one CPU instruction (just create a pointer to somewhere on the stack).

Comment: @J.Dow in case that is the solution to your answer, consider answering your own question and mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Setting GOGC=off improved performance (down to less than 100ms). Why?
becaue of [escape analysis](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CompilerOptimizations#escape-analysis-and-inlining). When you build with `go build -gcflags -m` the compiler prints whatever allocations escapes to heap. It really depends on your machine and GO compiler version but when the compiler decides that the allocation should move to heap it means 2 things:
1. the allocation will take longer (since "allocating" on the stack is just 1 cpu instruction)
2. the GC will have to clean up that memory later - costing more CPU time
for my machine, the allocation of 65536 bytes escapes to heap and 65535 doesn't.
that's why 1 bytes changed the whole proccess from 200ms to 30s. Amazing..

Answer (score 4):

Note/Update 2021: as [Tapir Liui](https://twitter.com/TapirLiu/) notes in [Go101](https://github.com/go101/go101) with [this tweet](https://twitter.com/go100and1/status/1436322149355061248):

> As of Go 1.17, Go runtime will allocate the elements of *slice* `x` on stack if the compiler proves they are only used in the current goroutine and `N <= 64KB`:
>
> ```
> var x = make([]byte, N)
> ```
>
> And Go runtime will allocate the *array* `y` on stack if the compiler proves it is only used in the current goroutine and `N <= 10MB`:
>
> ```
> var y [N]byte
> ```
>
> Then how to allocated (the elements of) a *slice* which **size is larger than 64KB but not larger than 10MB on stack** (and the slice is only used in one goroutine)?
>
> Just use the following way:
>
> ```
> var y [N]byte
> var x = y[:]
> ```

Considering stack allocation is faster than heap allocation, that would have a direct effect on your test, for `alloc` equals to 65536 and more.

Tapir [adds](https://twitter.com/go100and1/status/1437805732192088070):

> In fact, we could allocate slices with arbitrary sum element sizes on stack.
>
> ```golang
> const N = 500 * 1024 * 1024 // 500M
> var v byte = 123
>
> func createSlice() byte {
>  var s = []byte{N: 0}
>  for i := range s { s[i] = v }
>  return s[v]
> }
> ```
>
> Changing 500 to 512 make program crash.

Answer (score 0):

the reason is very simple.

const alloc int = 65535

`0x0000 00000 (example.go:8)     TEXT    "".main(SB), ABIInternal, $65784-0`

const alloc int = 65536

`0x0000 00000 (example.go:8)     TEXT    "".main(SB), ABIInternal, $248-0`

the difference is where the slice are created.